# Next.JS custom server restarting when trying to use Socket.io, address already in use :::3000

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, next.js

Whenever I try to run the function `refreshStock()` in an endpoint in one of the API endpoints `/api/seller/deactivate` it gives me this error:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1318:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1366:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1452:7)
    at C:\Users\***\Documents\GitHub\***\***\.next\server\pages\api\seller\deactivate.js:191:10
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command
```

It looks like it's trying to restart the server, but it happens after it compiles, is there something I'm doing wrong, I've followed a couple of tutorials on medium, and they give this same type of code, just not ES Modules. I want to use ES Modules because it is what my database functions are written in.

Server.js:

```
import express from 'express';
import { createServer } from 'http';
import next from 'next';
import models from './server/models';
import { genStock } from './server/lib/functions';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT || '3000', 10);
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const nextApp = next({ dev });
const nextHandler = nextApp.getRequestHandler();

const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);

const Users = models.users;

io.use(async (socket, next) => {
  const err = new Error('Unauthorized');
  err.data = { message: 'Unauthorized, please try again later.' };
  try {
    if (!socket.handshake.auth.token) return next(err);
    let user = await Users.findOne({
      where: {
        socket_token: socket.handshake.auth.token,
      },
    });
    if (!user) {
      console.log('unauthenticated socket');
      socket.disconnect();
      next(err);
    }
    await Users.update(
      { socket_id: socket.id },
      {
        where: {
          socket_token: socket.handshake.auth.token,
        },
      },
    );
    next();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    next(e);
  }
});

io.on('connection', async (socket) => {
  // Works fine
  const stock = await genStock();
  socket.emit('updateStock', stock);
});

// Fails with address already in use :::3000
export async function refreshStock() {
  const stock = await genStock();
  io.emit('updateStock', stock);
}

nextApp.prepare().then(async () => {
  app.all('*', (req, res) => nextHandler(req, res));

  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});
```

This is meant to refresh the stock after a seller deactivates their account and sends all users the new stock.

/api/seller/deactivate

```
....
await refreshStock();
....
```

Comment: Going to try to use a different port for the Socket.IO server when I get up in the morning, I'll update when I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I just split up the WebSocket server and the next.js one. I have whitelisted local IPs that may appear to only allow server-to-server communication. Although I don't think this is full-proof as there is most likely a better way to have this type of communication but for now it works.

```
/**
 * This server cannot be imported in /api folders, it won't work.
 * Although it can import other functions
 * */

import express from 'express';
import { createServer } from 'http';
import session from 'express-session';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import { genStock } from './server/lib/stockFunctions';
import { sessionStore } from './server/lib/session';
import passport from './server/lib/passport';
import models from './server/models';

const authorizedIPs = ['::1', '127.0.0.1', '::ffff:127.0.0.1'];

const Users = models.users;
const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);

const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: `http://localhost:3000`,
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    credentials: true,
  },
});

const wrap = (middleware) => (socket, next) => middleware(socket.request, {}, next);
io.use(
  wrap(
    session({
      secret: "---",
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: true,
      cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
        path: '/',
        sameSite: 'lax',
      },
      store: sessionStore,
    }),
  ),
);
io.use(wrap(passport.initialize()));
io.use(wrap(passport.session()));

io.use(async (socket, next) => {
  const err = new Error('Unauthorized');
  err.data = { message: 'Unauthorized, please try again later.' };
  try {
    const user = socket.request.user;
    if (!user) return next(err);
    await Users.update(
      { socket_id: socket.id },
      {
        where: {
          id: user.id,
        },
      },
    );
    next();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    next(e);
  }
});

io.on('connection', async (socket) => {
  const stock = await genStock();
  socket.emit('updateStock', stock);
});

app.post('/refresh-stock', async function (req, res) {
  const ip = req.ip;

  if (!authorizedIPs.includes(ip)) {
    console.log(ip);
    return res.status(401).json({ success: false });
  }

  const newStock = await genStock();
  io.emit('updateStock', newStock);
  return res.status(200).json({ success: true });
});

httpServer.listen(3001);

console.log(`> Websockets ready on http://localhost:3001`);
```